# How do I turn off Node.js Express (ejs template engine) errors for production?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

When I'm on a development server and there is an error, Express sends the traceback as a response.

However, this is not good for production. I don't want anyone seeing my trackback.

How can I turn this off?

Note: I'm using EJS as a template engine - this may be the cause, and not express. When I have  an undefined variable in the ejs template, for example, ejs renders the traceback and displays it to the user on a white page.

Comment: Which version of express you're using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest version of Express use smart default error handler.

In `development` mode it sends full stack trace back to the browser, while in `production` mode it sends only `500 Internal Server Error`.

To take advantage of it you should set proper `NODE_ENV` before running your application.

For example, to run your app in production mode:

```
NODE_ENV=production node application.js
```

---

But if you don't like this default behavior, you could define your own error handler:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

Note that error handler must be the last middleware in chain, so it should be defined in the bottom of your `application.js` file.

---

If you need more information, see:

- [Express official documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling)
- [Blog post about error handling in Express](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/12/error-handling-express-js-applications/)

Answer (score 6):

So errors can be coming from express or ejs. In case of:

1. Express error : Use custom error handling to override the default behaviour. Simply don't send back the error. Read about it on the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) page. Or you can use already existing middleware such [errorhandler](https://github.com/expressjs/errorhandler) like Leonid said to override it.
2. Template error : Due to jade/ejs etc. Again handle the errors instead of default behaviour which is to send them to client. Use a callback and check for errors. If there is don't display them, instead show an error page.

   ```
   res.render(your_template, {}, function(err, html) {
       if(err) {
           res.redirect('/error');
       } else {
           res.send(html);
       }
   });
   ```