# Disable Express error handling for critical errors

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    throw new Error('critical');
})
```

makes Express server to catch a critical error and output it, while I want it to crash.

Adding an error handler doesn't replace the default handler.

How can Express error handling be disabled for critical errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn off Node.js Express (ejs template engine) errors for production?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354022/how-do-i-turn-off-node-js-express-ejs-template-engine-errors-for-production)

Comment: @Muhammad No, it isn't. Disable *error handling*, not errors.

Comment: Also, if you are worried about stack traces getting sent to the client, you can set the environment variable NODE_ENV=production. This will send "internal error 500" instead of a stack trace from the default error handler.

Comment: @AndyCarlson Thanks, discovered it recently, quite useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your server to **crash** in the event of a critical error, you can define an [error-handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). This is done by defining a function with **4 parameters**, the first being the error. This will be called when an error is thrown. You can check the error and determine if it's critical, and if so, call `process.exit`.

```
const app = require('express')()

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('critical')
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.message === 'critical') {
    process.exit(1)
  } else {
    // carry on listening
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I wonder if there is more idiomatic way to do this in Express rather than calling process.exit explicitly.

Comment: @estus Can you accept the answer by clicking the check mark? I need the points to afford offering bounties on my questions.

Comment: I guess I can, I don't see better ways to do this. Thanks again.