# Prevent Express from showing errors to Jade template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm not sure how to prevent this, if there's an error to do with my Jade template it's shown on the frontend even in prod.

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: How do you render view? Show the code please.

Comment: exports.about = (req, res) => {
  res.render('about', {
    title: 'About'
  });
};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the errors instead of default behaviour which is to send them to the client. Use a callback and check for the errors. If there are any errors then don't display them, instead show an error page like below.

```
 res.render(your_template, {}, function(err, html) {
        if(err) {
            res.redirect('/error');
        } else {
            res.send(html);
        }
    });
```

Ref: [How do I turn off Node.js Express (ejs template engine) errors for production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354022/how-do-i-turn-off-node-js-express-ejs-template-engine-errors-for-production)

Comment: Is there a way to add a handler for all routes?

Comment: @AnthonyMayfield Create express error handler `app.use(err, req, res, next)`, and call `next(err)` from routers. In this handler, use `res.redirect`.